# How i retrieve Data From MS SQL 2012 using Android App

Tags: android, sql-server-2012-express

I want to know is there any way to connect my android app with MS SQL Server 2012 and retrieve data from there instead of using `phpmyAdmin.` i know same type of question has been asked already but that was not clear and answers were not helpful as well. i'm searching for full tutorial as I'm pretty new to this thing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect your app with **MS SQL Server 2012** but for using this approach you can create **Web Services**.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever database you are using like MySql or MSSql. You have to do two things.

1. First, you have to create **`API`** which provides output in `json` or `xml`
2. Second, you have to access the API from the android application.